# AD clients try server management IP

Tags: windows, active-directory, firewall

My servers have two NICs, one for LAN and the other for management. Those are separate VLANs.

I have [disabled registration of management NIC in DNS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2023004/steps-to-avoid-registering-unwanted-nic-s-in-dns-on-a-mulithomed-domai).
There are no records in DNS with management network IPs.
I even cleared `Client for Microsoft Networks` and `File and Printer Sharing` check-boxes in management adapter properties.

Yet, in firewall logs, I still see clients trying connect to server management IP, ports 389, 445 etc.
Strangest behavior is the server itself, LAN IP trying to connect to self management IP port 389.

Yes, the firewall blocks all of these requests, but I want to configure this properly and eliminate such requests which is nothing but noise in firewall logs.

Environment is mixed of Windows Server 2012, 2016 both core and regular. Windows 10 and 8.1 clients.

**UPDATE**

Management network is for remote administrative access such as SSH, RDP, monitoring tools etc.
I do not want any domain related activities coming/going via management network, those must stay in LAN. Ideally management VLAN will be a physical separate LAN on other hardware.

Configuration for NICs look like this:

```
Ethernet adapter mgmt:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c1a6:4b40:beb0:a627%22
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :


Ethernet adapter domain:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::48a3:e974:bc0d:837%16
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.5
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
```

Comment: For the management NICs are they assigned an IP address in the same subnet as the LAN? Are you using VLANs?

Comment: Yes, separate VLANs. Sorry, I forgot to clarify this.

Comment: Would you please add the interface and switch VLAN configs? You should not be seeing requests from the LAN VLAN to the management VLAN.

Comment: I don't understand what value the management NIC has and why you configured the server with a management NIC. Why do you need a separate NIC to manage the server? Dual/multi-homed Domain Controllers are not recommended.

Comment: Check your vlan configuration. the x.x.10,x network should be isolated from the x.x.1.x network. they should not be _able_ to talk to each other, no ping, nothing...

Comment: @Larryc they can't talk. The point is they are trying to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the PublishAddresses registry value on the domain controller and specify the desired IP address for registration.

https://alasdaircs.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/a-little-active-directory-dns-server-magic/

```
Key: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters  
Value: PublishAddresses  
Type: REG_SZ
```

Comment: It appears to have mostly helped. However attempts to management IP port 445 is still ongoing. PublishAddresses does not work for SMB?